Get row order grouped by one of the columns
Assuming I have the following table:



id
category_id
item_id
created_at




7
11
106
2024-05-06


6
3
102
2024-05-06


5
11
101
2024-05-05


4
9
98
2024-05-04


3
3
97
2024-05-03


2
1
91
2024-05-02


1
11
89
2024-05-01



How can I select all the rows, and add a column that represents the order of the creation for each item grouped by its category?
The result should be:



id
category_id
item_id
item_order_by_category
created_at




7
11
106
3
2024-05-06


6
3
102
2
2024-05-06


5
11
101
2
2024-05-05


4
9
98
1
2024-05-04


3
3
97
1
2024-05-03


2
1
91
1
2024-05-02


1
11
89
1
2024-05-01



It can either be by the order of the id column or the created_at column
Is it doable with a query with good performance? Or I will need to add some more information like a relationship table for that?

Look into Row_Number  function with a partition by

Thank you! just read it now on MS docs. I am currently trying (no success yet). What I tried after reading a bit in the docs was: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY category_id). It looks like I'm getting closer, but I will need to read a bit more to see where is my mistake

@pileup Just change the order by to created_at.

Its important to PARTITION BY category_ID and ORDER BY created_at or ID. We also need to order by ID or created_at decending at the end.
SELECT 
 id, 
 category_id, 
 item_id,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_ID ORDER BY created_at) as     item_order_by_category,
 created_at
FROM Example
ORDER BY id desc

fiddle



id
category_id
item_id
item_order_by_category
created_at




7
11
106
3
2024-05-06


6
3
102
2
2024-05-06


5
11
101
2
2024-05-05


4
9
98
1
2024-05-04


3
3
97
1
2024-05-03


2
1
91
1
2024-05-02


1
11
89
1
2024-05-01



